# When to extend ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to add a method or two to ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition; when should I load my code? I tried loading it via `require` immediately after Application.initialize! in config/environment.rb but then everything errors out with -

```
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition (NameError)
```

By the way I am on Rails 3.0.3. And the code I am trying to load looks like this -

```
class << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition
  def my_extension(*args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    ... some stuff is done here ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the source file in `config/initializers`. Any `.rb` file found there should be loaded automatically by Rails.